# Not losing a character in a Regex

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this sample:

```
example <- data.frame(data=c("Annie;7;3%;Luciana;9;2%;Lucas;1;10%"))
```

And I need to separate it so every name has the proper information in the same column. Also, I do not know how long the "data" is, so I created a long vector with names

```
names<- paste0("name ",1:70,"")
```

And I separated the example like this:

```
example <- example %>% separate(data,into=c(names),sep="(%;[A-z])")
```

In this way I am able to separate all the cases, but I am missing the first and the last character (the only one that cares is the first one):

```
Annie;7;3 | uciana;9;2 | ucas;1;10%
```

There is any way to split the information without losing the first character? I am not good with regex.

Thank you!

Comment: Try using strsplit()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most immediate solution to your problem is with a positive lookahead assertion. This means that the split will occur on the separator but not include the positive look ahead capture group. Positive lookahead is denoted with `(?=)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
example %>% 
   separate(data, into=c(names), sep="%;(?=[A-z])")
```

Answer (score 1):

One base R option would be to use `strsplit` combine with `do.call`:

```
example <- data.frame(data=c("Annie;7;3%;Luciana;9;2%;Lucas;1;10%"))
out <- strsplit(as.character(example$data), '(?<=%);', perl=TRUE) 
data.frame(do.call(rbind, out))

          X1           X2          X3
1 Annie;7;3% Luciana;9;2% Lucas;1;10%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read.csv(header = FALSE, text = gsub("%;", "%,", example$data), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#          V1           V2          V3
#1 Annie;7;3% Luciana;9;2% Lucas;1;10%
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)   
cSplit(example, 'data', sep='%;')
```